# Symfony como obtener todos los productos de una categoria One to Many

Tags: symfony, symfony5

He seguido los pasos para crear los el primer proyecto pero tengo el problema que no se como solucionar con las entidades de una relación de uno a Muchos.
En otras palabras como un artículo que solo tiene una categoría hasta aquí bien.
Pero cuando Quiero a con el id de la categoría se muestre, todos sus artículos no lo consigo.
(Entity)

```
Product.php 
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $Price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->Price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $Price): self
    {
        $this->Price = $Price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

   
}
```

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->removeElement($product)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getCategory() === $this) {
                $product->setCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Controlador Product**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
// ...
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Product;


class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/product", name="product")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ProductController',
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/createProduct", name="createProduct")
     */
    public function createProduct(): Response
    {
        $category = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Category::class)
        ->find(1);
        

        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('Monitor Lg2');
        $product->setPrice(270.20);
        $product->setDescription('Lg 4k resolutiona and smart tv, hdmi, etc..');

        // relates this product to the category
        $product->setCategory($category);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($category);
        $entityManager->persist($product);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response(
            'Saved new product with id: '.$product->getId()
            .' and new category with id: '.$category->getId()
        );
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/product/{id}", name="product_id")
     */
    public function show(int $id): Response
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Product::class)
            ->find($id);
           
        dd($product);

        $categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();
        // ...
        return new Response(
            'Saved new product with id: '.$product->getId()
            .' and new category with id: '.$category->getId()
        );

    
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/category_list/{id}", name="category_list") 
     */

    public function showCategoryProducts(int $id): Response
    {
        $category = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Category::class)
            ->find($id);

        $products = $category->getProducts();
        dd($products);
        // ...
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que tal me estoy dejando algo, pero si pudieran explicarme la forma correcta, de relacionar las tablas.
Mi idea es que se pueda ver la categoría y su lista de productos

Comment: Todo parace correcto y bien relacionado. Estas seguro de que esa `Category` tiene `products` asociados?

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista parece que está bien. ¿Podrías poner el método `toArray()` o recorrer la colección? Muchas veces no muestra lo que contiene si no lo recorres o lo pasas a array. Haz esto y dime si te funciona:

```
$category->getProducts()->toArray();
```